# How important to use whether during speaking?

Tags: spoken-english, error

Most of the time when I am speaking, I forget to use "**whether**", and when I reach the end of my sentence I find that I had to apply it in my sentence then I correct my sentence with the addition of "whether".

For example, consider this sentence:  "I don't know I can say it to you" when I reach to the end of the sentence I find that I have to use "or not" at the end of my sentence (... it to you **or not**), therefore I had to apply "whether" (I don't know **whether** I).

1- I want to know from the grammatical point, this slipping up is correct?
2- Do the native persons fall in difficulty to understand my mean?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? "Whether" can be used in several ways.

Comment: @TypeIA I added an example

Answer (score 2):

"I dont know I can say it to you" is ungrammatical to begin with. It should already contain "whether" or "if." This requirement doesn't arise from adding "... or not" to the end. The following are all correct. (In each case I've replaced "say it to you" with "tell you," which is more idiomatic.)

> - I don't know **if** I can tell you.
> - I don't know **if** I can tell you **or not**.
> - I don't know **whether** I can tell you **or not**.
> - I don't know **whether or not** I can tell you.

In all cases, you need "if" or "whether" when referring to conditional knowledge of a true-or-false fact.